# What is the norm of this vector?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have the vector:

$$(-\sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta) \varphi' - \cos(\varphi)\sin(\theta)\theta', \cos(\varphi)\sin(\theta)\varphi' + \sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta)\theta',\cos(\theta)\theta') $$

where $\varphi=\varphi(t) ; \theta = \theta(t);$ and $\varphi'= \frac{d \varphi}{dt};\theta'= \frac{d \theta}{dt};$

I have the answer to be : $\sqrt{1+\varphi'^2\cos^2\theta}$.

I have tried and tried simplifying this to get the answer, but I cannot seem to. Does anyone see something that I cannot, how to get this?

Comment: its a straight-forward calculation using $||(x,y,z)||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. You have to multiply everything out, and then simplify using the relation $(sin(\phi))^2+(cos(\phi))^2=1$

Comment: Well, that's what I thought looking at everything, but then got stuck. I'll try again

Comment: I tried again. Cannot do it.

Comment: hm, just tried it, doesn't work. Are you sure your vector is correct? If your expression comes from some previous calculation, it might help to show the starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be the derivative of $\vec r=(\cos\varphi(t)\cos\theta(t),\sin\varphi(t)\cos\theta(t),\sin\theta(t))$ if you want to get the given solution.

$\dfrac{d\vec r}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial\vec r}{\partial\theta}\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}+\dfrac{\partial\vec r}{\partial\varphi}\dfrac{d\varphi}{dt}=$

$=(-\varphi'\sin\varphi\cos\theta-\theta'\cos\varphi\sin\theta,\varphi'\cos\varphi\cos\theta -\theta'\sin\varphi\sin\theta,\theta'\cos\theta)$

$\require{enclose}\enclose{downdiagonalstrike,updiagonalstrike}{\left|\dfrac{d\vec r}{dt}\right|=\sqrt{1+\varphi'^2\cos^2\theta}}$

**added**

With the detailed calculations, the given solution doesn't follow, at most $\sqrt{\theta'^2+\varphi'^2\cos\theta}$. We can recover the given solution redefining $\varphi'$ as $\dfrac{d\varphi}{d\theta}$, but to many assumptions. I don't delete the answer because maybe some calculations are usefull.

$$\left|\dfrac{d\vec r}{dt}\right|^2=x^2+y^2+z^2=$$

$$=(-\varphi'\sin\varphi\cos\theta-\theta'\cos\varphi\sin\theta)^2+(\varphi'\cos\varphi\cos\theta -\theta'\sin\varphi\sin\theta)^2+(\theta'\cos\theta)^2=$$ $$=\varphi'^2\sin^2\varphi\cos^2\theta+\theta'^2\cos^2\varphi\sin^2\theta+2\theta'\cos\varphi\sin\theta\;\varphi'\sin\varphi\cos\theta+$$

$$+\varphi'^2\cos^2\varphi\cos^2\theta+\theta'^2\sin^2\varphi\sin^2\theta-2\varphi'\cos\varphi\cos\theta\;\theta'\sin\varphi\sin\theta+\theta'^2\cos^2\theta=$$

$$=\varphi'^2\cos^2\theta(\sin^2\varphi+\cos^2\varphi)+\theta'^2\sin^2\theta(\sin^2\varphi+\cos^2\varphi)+\theta'^2\cos^2\theta=$$

$$=\varphi'^2\cos^2\theta+\theta'^2(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)=\theta'^2+\varphi'^2\cos\theta$$

Comment: Pardon me, but how do you statements qualify as an answer?

Comment: Ah, now I see: the OP's vector doesn't have the given length.  Excuse me, please.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe As the OP stated, there is a contradiction between the given solution and the given data. Probably it helps to show a starting point resembling to the given data and from where the given solution follows. I've fixed a lot of problems this way.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe No problem :)

Comment: This is it. But still cannot see this last line, where is comes from!